# run PhoneGap command using DOS

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I am learning phonegap.
After watching this video on youtube some videos
I realized that my CMD  does not have a "cordova" and 'phoneGap' command.
I installed Phonegap for windows, but what can i do to run this command?

In the video the author use this command at '11.12'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your environment first.

There is a one-step installer PhoneGap installer for Windows:
http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/

But if you intend to use the command-line (and you should) you have to take some previous steps:

- install node and NPM
- install and configure Git
- install the Android SDK and the Java JDK
- include all of that on your PATH environment variable

There is a full tutorial here:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/cli/index.html

Comment: I had problems in my PC during installation, i tried several times.
I know via COmmand line is the best way, 
can i install plugin just simply copying the .js file?

Comment: You can run the contents of the www folder from any modern browser but you will need the Android SDK to compile the actual app

Comment: An intermediate approach is to install node, npm and cordova, create a project and run "cordova serve" to run a test web server that reloads everytime you modify a file.